# MySQL DATE_FORMAT() Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value

Tags: mysql

When I run `DATE_FORMAT('test', '%W %M %Y')` I get `null` returned.

I'm running an update to my table `extras` where the column is a nullable varchar, but when I run eg.

```
update extras
set extras.`value` = DATE_FORMAT('test', '%W %M %Y');
```

I get the following error:

```
[22001][1292] Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: 'test'
```

`extras.value` is a varchar column with datetime values some of which are not valid dates. I want to update the column to null when the datetime is invalid ie. just a string as in this case 'test'.

Comment: Do the valid dates have a consistent format? You can use `STR_TO_DATE()` to parse that. Then check if this returns `NULL`.

Comment: @Barmar doesn't work.  doing STR_TO_DATE on an invalid date in an UPDATE/INSERT/etc statement is a fatal error, even if you check if the results are null, even if you just use it in a WHERE clause.  https://dbfiddle.uk/ypxKmJ94  FWIW I consider this a horrible bug in mysql.  It *should* only produce a fatal error if the results of the date parsing are directly used to set a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check does the value is valid date with regular expression.

Example - the most simple pattern which does not check for value validity (and allows, for example, '2022-25-78', in this case the whole UPDATE will fail):

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  src_value VARCHAR(255),
  dst_value VARCHAR(255)
);
INSERT INTO test (src_value) VALUES ('test'), (CURRENT_DATE);
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| id | src_value | dst_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test | *null* |
| 2 | 2022-11-22 | *null* |

```
UPDATE test
SET dst_value = DATE_FORMAT(src_value, '%W %M %Y')
WHERE src_value REGEXP '^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}$' ;
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| id | src_value | dst_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test | *null* |
| 2 | 2022-11-22 | Tuesday November 2022 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jI5A0GIr)

Comment: @ysth That's what I meant. Clarification added, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When the STRICT_TRANS_TABLES sql_mode is enabled, any date/time parsing error becomes a fatal error.  You have to disable it or use a regex to validate the date string (which is very messy) before using it as a date.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nyT5yDBe)